# Why output is negative in Fast Power question?

Tags: java

Calculate the a<sup>n</sup> % b where `a`, `b` and `n` are all 32-bit positive integers.

Example
For 2<sup>31</sup> % 3 = 2

For 100<sup>1000</sup> % 1000 = 0
The time complexity is O(logn)

I am using recursive method to solve the problem but I do not know why the output is -54791 because some test can be passed. Also for the recursive return value, I do not know where should I put.

When I submit:

```
Wrong Answer

47% test cases passedTotal runtime 2375 ms

Input

a = 11
b = 123898
n = 12345

Output
-54791

Expected
78433
```

```
public class Solution {
    /**
     * @param a: A 32bit integer
     * @param b: A 32bit integer
     * @param n: A 32bit integer
     * @return: An integer
     */

    int res = 1;
    public int fastPower(int a, int b, int n) {
        // write your code here

        if(n == 0){
            if(b == 1){
                return 0;
            }
            return res % b;
        }
        if(n % 2 == 0){
            int temp = fastPower(a, b, n/2);
            res =  temp * temp;

        }else{
            int temp = fastPower(a, b, n/2);
            res =  temp * temp * a;

        }

        return res % b;
    }

    //return fastPower(a,b,n) % b;

}
```

Comment: Please note that the maximum value which can be stored in an integer is `2^31-1`. Since `res` is an integer, you pretty much have an overflow.

Comment: By "an", do you mean `a` multiplied by `n`, or do you mean `a` to the power of `n`, as implied by your method name `fastPower`?  To include an exponent in your question, use the HTML tag `sup`: `a<sup>n</sup> % b`.

Answer (score 0):

> **a pow (n) mod (b):**

```
public static int fastPower(int a, int n, int b ) {
            long res = 1, temporary = a;

            while (n != 0) {
                if (n % 2 == 1) {
                    res = (res * temporary) % b;
                }
                temporary = (temporary * temporary) % b;
                n /= 2;
            }
            return (int) res % b;

        }
```

> **Usage:**

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(fastPower(2, 31, 3));
        //a = 11,b = 123898, n = 12345
        System.out.println(fastPower(11, 12345, 123898));
  }
```